Download file from sharepoint using talend
I am trying to download the file from share point to local folder using unix script.
Can someone please share me if you have any script handy or any guidence appreciated.
I have tried with Curl command by passing authentication. I see file is download, but when i try to open the download file, it's saying file corrupted.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please [edit] your question and show your script as a [mre]. How exactly do you try to open the file?
